# How to responsively set width of button according to the width of the image using CSS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is what I have [currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyKVN.png) with the code below. I'm trying to have the button span the width of the responsive image on resize. Right now it shrinks almost half its size when resizing instead of staying align with the image. This may be a jQuery question, I'm not entirely sure.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img-box col-lg-12 text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="window.location='beginReservation.php'">Book Seat Now</button><br>
                <img class="bg img-responsive img-center" src="images/homepage.jpg" alt="Book Seat">
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
   .img-box {
     background: white;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding: 0px;
     display:inline-block;
    }

    .btn {
      background: rgb(179,0,14);
      border: rgb(179,0,14);
      padding: 0.5% 32.75%;
      border-radius: 0px;   
      margin:0 auto;    
    }

   .bg {
     margin:0 auto; 
   }
```

Comment: If your image is 100% width of it's container then just set button width to 100%

Comment: @Huangism and than scale it's parent (img-box) to your desired width

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman I would imagine the width is taken care of with `col-lg-12`

Comment: Refer to bootstrap documentation for navbar
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: @Kelly you are making .img-box to display:inline-block; remove that rule and give a try.

Comment: Removing the display:inline-block and scaling img-box accordingly did the trick!

Comment: @Kelly Chandra Shekhar answered this question with that solution, I'd suggest marking his answer as the right one to close your question

Comment: Will do! You have to wait a certain amount of time to mark an answer as right. Just now able to.

Comment: @kelly ..... Cool ... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  display:inline-block from this class `.img-box{}`